# SQL Server - count the number of living grandparents

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm homelearning databases and currently trying to solve the following problem:

> Select id and name of people who are grandchildren. Also select for
>   each person the number of their still living grandparents.

My table is looking the following way:

> id, name, date_of_birth, date_of_death (is NULL when the person is
>   alive), gender, father_id, mother_id

I was able to solve the part with selecting the id and name of people who are grandchildren the following way:

```
SELECT b.name, b.id
FROM persons a
JOIN persons b ON c.father_id = a.id or a.mother_id = a.id
JOIN persons c on p.father_id = c.id 
WHERE b.father_id = a.id or b.mother_id = a.id;
```

However, I am unable to solve the part with the number of still living grandparents for each person.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: It makes it easier for people to answer if you create an SQL fiddle.   I have created one you can fork/modify as you wish.  I suggest including this link with your question.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/441ad0/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of joining the tables.  I think you are all confused by the table aliases on the self-joins.  So give them *meaningful* aliases:

- `p` for the person
- `pp` for the person's parents
- `gp` for the person's grandparents

Then, once you have the `JOIN`s correct, the rest is mostly aggregation:

```
SELECT p.name, p.id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gp.date_of_death IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM persons p JOIN    -- persons
     persons pp        -- parents
     ON pp.id IN (p.father_id, p.mother_id) JOIN
     persons gp
     ON gp.id IN (pp.father_id, pp.mother_id)
GROUP BY p.name, p.id;
```

Note the conditional sum, which includes the date of death.

Comment: Much more elegant than my answer.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to join 3 copies of the table, group by person and count conditionally the number of living grandparents:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
  count(case when p2.date_of_death is null then 1 end) living_grandparents 
FROM persons p
JOIN persons p1 ON p1.id IN (p.father_id, p.mother_id) 
JOIN persons p2 on p2.id IN (p1.father_id, p1.mother_id) 
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

For MySql the condition could be simplified to:

```
sum(p2.date_of_death is null) living_grandparents
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SQL Fiddle for the solution :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/441ad0/16

```
    select 
  (
    select 
      count(*) 
    from 
      people 
    where 
      (
        id = p.fatherId 
        or id = p.motherId
      ) 
      and (
        fatherId in (
          select 
            id 
          from 
            people 
          where 
            dod is null
        ) 
        or motherId in (
          select 
            id 
          from 
            people 
          where 
            dod is null
        )
      )
  ) as mycount, 
  p.name, 
  p.id, 
  p.fatherId, 
  p.motherId 
FROM 
  people p 
WHERE 
  p.fatherId in (
    SELECT 
      id 
    from 
      people 
    where 
      id = p.fatherId 
      and fatherId in (
        SELECT 
          id 
        from 
          people 
        where 
          1 = 1
      )
  ) 
  OR p.motherId in (
    SELECT 
      id 
    from 
      people 
    where 
      id = p.motherId 
      and motherId in (
        SELECT 
          id 
        from 
          people 
        where 
          1 = 1
      )
  )
```